# Multiple context menus in a single activity,each on different lists

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contextmenu

I am trying to implement two context menus in the same activity but registered to different lists in android. I have been using the layouts as below by using framelayout:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

         <include
            android:id="@+id/container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/admin_0" />

         <include
            android:id="@+id/container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/admin_1"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

The layout `admin_0` contains a listview while `admin_1` contains another one. This all is implemented and instantiated in the same activity. I did refer to some posts about this implementation but didn't understand the process.

This is the only single menu we can implement in the `menus.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:id="@+id/Delete" android:title="Delete"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/Reply"  android:title="Reply"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/Forward" android:title="Forward"></item> 

    </menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
remove include source in xml.
and then, in code, you can display another xml using inflater.
but, function is located in one java code.
ex)

```
LinearLayout contentsLayout = ( LinearLayout )findViewById( R.id.contentsLayout );
LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater )getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
inflater.inflate( R.layout.anotherLayout, contentsLayout, true );
```